# delphi xe6 style designer does not work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

in Delphi XE6, I add a StyleBook to the form and double click on it. Designing menu appears. I see the buttons: load, add, save etc. When I click on them nothing happens. It shows designer but when I click, it clicks on the form. When I click on "Apply" button, it opens the devices combo box.

I am using:

Delphi XE6 Update 1

Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Paralles Desktop Build 9.0.24237

Mac OS 10.9.4

[image: It shows style designer but still form designer is opened]

Comment: When I use `File->New-?FireMonkey Desktop Application`, choose HD Application, drop a `TStyleBook` on the form, double-click it, and choose `Load`, I get a file open dialog. Can you post **exact** steps to reproduce this problem? (It's clear why "Apply" doesn't do anything, as you've done nothing with a style to *apply*. What would you apply *I've done absolutely nothing* to, and how would you measure it's effect?)

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Tomohiro-san at embarcadero quality centre, when I changed dpi settings of virtual windows the problem has gone.